# Add header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"); to PHP page with no products

Tags: php

I'm trying to add `header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");` to the following PHP so that pages without any products show as Not Found.

```
if(@$usecsslayout) print '<div class="' . $cs . 'products">';
$totrows=ect_num_rows($allprods);
if(ect_num_rows($allprods)==0)
    print (! @$usecsslayout ? '<tr><td colspan="' . $productcolumns . '" align="center">' : '') . '<p>'.$GLOBALS['xxNoPrds'].'</p>' . (! @$usecsslayout ? '</td></tr>' : '');
else while($rs=ect_fetch_assoc($allprods)){
```

I have added `header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");` in various places after `if(ect_num_rows($allprods)==0)` and the file hangs.

If I replace the print element `(print (! @$usecsslayout ? '<tr><td colspan="' . $productcolumns . '" align="center">' : '') . '<p>'.$GLOBALS['xxNoPrds'].'</p>' . (! @$usecsslayout ? '</td></tr>' : '');)` with `header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");` then a Not Found is generated.

My problem is that I want a Not Found combined with the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

When using `header` you are not allowed to have any output before the `header` is called.
`print '<div class="' . $cs . 'products">';` is output and therefor, the header function is not working.

You won't be able to first print the `div` and then display a 404

Comment: Okay. If that's not possible how do I get it to redirect to 404.php instead.

Comment: Without any output. Make sure you do not have any output (`print`, `echo`) before you call the `header` function

Comment: I gone with this but it returns a 302.if(ect_num_rows($allprods)==0)
                   header("Location:/");
  else while($rs=ect_fetch_assoc($allprods)){ Now do I make it a 301?